# How do I make this python program executable in other computer?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyinstaller, exe

I made this QR scanner that checks if a url is safe, I´ve tried to use pyinstaller on windows to make it executable on someone else's computer (also windows) but I never got it to work, how do I do it? I need this for a college project

```
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(5, 640)
cam.set(6, 480)

camera = True

while camera == True:
    sucess, frame = cam.read()

    for i in decode(frame):
        page = i.data.decode("utf-8")
        print(page)

        if "." in page:
            linkcheckeo = ("https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url="+page)
            respuesta = requests.get(linkcheckeo)
            respuesta = respuesta.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(respuesta, "html.parser")
            resultados = soup.find(id="bodyContent")
            titulo = resultados.find_all("b")
            titulo = titulo[0].text
            if titulo == "SAFE":
                print("SEGURO")
            elif titulo == "CAUTION":
                print("PRECAUCION")
            elif titulo == "WARNING":
                print("QR PELIGROSO")
            elif titulo == "UNTESTED":
                print("ORIGEN DESCONOCIDO")
            else:
                print(titulo)
        else:
            print("No detectamos un URL")
        time.sleep(6)

    cv2.imshow("Qr_Code_Scanner", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(3)
```

When I install it with pyinstaller it just opens and closes and doesn't do anything.

Comment: what platform are you on? Linux? Windows? mac?

Comment: if you want cross-platform you'l need to package a python interpreter with it.

Comment: I'm on windows, and the exe doesn't work on my pc either

Comment: please edit your question to include that you are on windows

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `auto-py-to-exe`, which is based on pyinstaller, but comes with a graphical user interface. I alsways found it easier to use, especially for debugging.
It can be installed with

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe.
```

To start, just open a terminal window and `cd` to the directory of you python-script and type

```
auto-py-to-exe yourscriptname.py
```

It will open a graphical user interface (either as window or in your browser). In the options there you can select 'console based' and 'log-level debug' in you first attempt to check for errors in case your application is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it, it was really simple, pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe didn't take the the pyzbar library into consideration, so it tried to create the .exe without it. I simply created the .exe as a full directory and added the pyzbar module file. It worked, thanks for your help.

[image: The file including all the libs]